# Magento indexController doesn't trigger

Tags: magento, controller

I'm working on a massgrid option in Magento. The problem is that my indexController doesn't get loaded. I think that there is a problem in the declaration of my classes.

This is my config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>Comp_Dhl_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
                <events>
                    <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                        <observers>
                            <Dhl_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                                <class>Dhl/observer</class>
                                <method>addMassAction</method>
                            </Dhl_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                        </observers>
                    </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                </events>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <admin>
        <routers>
            <todhl>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Comp_Dhl</module>
                    <frontName>todhl</frontName>
                </args>
            </todhl>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is my Grid.php

```
class Comp_Dhl_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{   
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'to_dhl',
            array('label' => $this->__('Sent to [DHL]'),
                  'url'   => $this->getUrl('/*/*/toDhl'),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The mass option: "Sent to [DHL]" shows up fine. Because I have this in my url: `$this->getUrl('/*/*/toDhl')` I have to add: `public function toDhlAction()` to my indexController.php

My indexController.php looks like:

```
class Comp_Dhl_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function toDhlAction(){      
        mail('to@me.com', 'controller works', 'the mass action controller works');
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }
}
```

And here is the problem, because I don't get the email that the indexController.php should trigger.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What URL are you supposing your controller to trigger at?

Comment: And, what is the relevant config for your module, ie `admin/routers/adminhtml/args/modules/...`, and are you sure it's being loaded?

Comment: I've updated the post and added the config.xml
When the mass action is selected it goes to: '/*/*/toDhl' (see my Grid.php)